# Maintain order of the value of the mapped column in array while joining on items inside an array column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Maintain order of the value of the mapped column in array while joining on items inside an array column in pyspark dataframe.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

            df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(2, [3, 4]), (3, [4]),(4, [3,5]),(5, [4,5]),(6, [5,4])], ["a", "b"])
            df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(3, "Three"), (4, "Four"),(5, "Five")], ["b", "c"])

            df3 = df1.alias("df1").join(
                df2.alias("df2"),
                F.expr("array_contains(df1.b, df2.b)"),
                "left"
            ).groupBy("df1.a").agg(
                F.first("df1.b").alias("b"),
                F.collect_list("df2.c").alias("c")
            )

            df3.show()
+---+------+-------------+
|  a|     b|            c|
+---+------+-------------+
|  2|[3, 4]|[Three, Four]|
|  3|   [4]|       [Four]|
|  4|[3, 5]|[Three, Five]|
|  5|[4, 5]| [Four, Five]|
|  6|[5, 4]| [Four, Five]|
+---+------+-------------+
```

Highlighted rows is not coming as per order specified.
**Like [4, 5] should return [Four, Five] and [5, 4] should return [Five, Four] instead of [Four, Five]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(2, [3, 4]), (3, [4]),(4, [3,5]),(5, [4,5]),(6, [5,4])], ["a", "b"])\
    .select("*",F.expr("posexplode(b) as (pos, key)"))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(3, "Three"), (4, "Four"),(5, "Five")], ["b", "c"]).withColumnRenamed("b","key")

df3 = df1.join(df2, on="key")\
    .orderBy("a", "pos")\
    .groupBy("a").agg(
    F.first("b").alias("b"),
    F.collect_list("c").alias("c")
)

df3.show()`

`+---+------+-------------+
|  a|     b|            c|
+---+------+-------------+
|  6|[5, 4]| [Five, Four]|
|  5|[4, 5]| [Four, Five]|
|  3|   [4]|       [Four]|
|  2|[3, 4]|[Three, Four]|
|  4|[3, 5]|[Three, Five]|
+---+------+-------------+`
```